# Как C# находит входящую точку?

Tags: c#

Например, я при помощи `dotnet new console` создал новый проект. Потом я переименовал `Program.cs`.
Запускаю через `dotnet run`, и все работает.

Почему?

Comment: согласно [статье](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) есть условия по которым компилятор C# определяет функцию - точку входа

Comment: А если Main нет, а просто один файл с содержимым: `Console.WriteLine(1231);`

Comment: Это значит, что его содержимое попадет в Main у сгенерированного компилятором класса.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements